# unexpected side-effect of 'using namespace' in psm1

Tags: powershell

(PS 5.1) I put a `using namespace` directive in a `psm1` to shorten some code. It then no longer recognizes a custom type I defined. Without the directive, all is peachy. It seems that a `using namespace` directive overrides things I did not expect it to.

Example: I have a `main.ps1`, and two modules.

**main.ps1**

```
using module .\classes.psm1 # using modules is needed to bring in classes, Import-Module won't cut it
Import-Module .\process.psm1 -Force # force reload
$MyList = Get-List # call function in module
$MyList[0].Bar # show a result
```

**classes.psm1**

```
Class Foo 
{
    [int]$Bar
}
```

**process.psm1**

```
function Get-List {
    $f = New-Object Foo
    $f.Bar = 42
    $list = [System.Collections.Generic.List[Foo]]::new()
    $list.Add($f)
    $list
}
```

This works fine. The trouble starts when I want to shorten things in **process.psm1**:

```
using namespace System.Collections.Generic

function Get-List {
    $f = New-Object Foo
    $f.Bar = 42
    $list = [List[Foo]]::new() # I just want a shorter way to declare a list
    $list.Add($f)
    $list
}
```

This complains about not recognizing type `Foo`. Why? (When I bring in `using module .\classes.psm1` in `process.psm1`, all is fine again.)

My point/question is: how does `using namespace` affect a module's capability to recognize other modules/files within a 'solution'? It find it rather counter-intuitive, but I am not a PS expert.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, PowerShell defers type name resolution until runtime - *unless* a script file contains at least one of the following:

- A `using` statement
- A `class` definition
- An `enum` definition

*Without* the `using namespace System.Collections.Generic` statement, PowerShell has no reason to attempt resolving any type names in `process.psm1` until *after* `[Foo]` has been loaded from `classes.psm1` and is resolvable/visible.

*With* the `using ...` statement on the other hand, PowerShell attempts to resolve the `[Foo]` type parameter in `[List[Foo]]` at parse-time - *before* `process.psm1` has actually been loaded into `main.ps1`, and so the error you see is thrown.

As you've found, adding an explicit `using module` reference to the module file containing `[Foo]` solves it, as `process.psm1` then no longer depends on the callers type resolution scope (which is not accessible at parse-time)